# NSFormCell placeholderString

Tags: cocoa, nsform

Just set up a NSForm and binded the first row to an NSFormCell in Interface Builder.

When I enter a text, I expected to get the result in [myFormCell placeholderString] or [myFormCell placeholderAttributedString] but there are nil.

Instead, I get it with [myFormCell stringValue].

What's the purpose of placeholderString? Am I doing right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The placeholder string is used when the user has not entered anything yet. So you can instruct the user what to enter without needing a separate label.